# Post thumbnail is not shown in wp-admin

Tags: posts, wp-admin, post-thumbnails, editor

I am currently working on a theme for a client and now just got into a problem: When I want to set an image (also existing/already uploaded images don't work) the editor just not accept it and don't set it as the post thumbnail for the post.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is an screenshot for the case that somebody didn't know, what I am talking about:

[image]

It's like this **before** and **after** the "change". So what's going on there?

Normal file upload is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was because of an script that was delivered with the **Options Framework**. There was a little piece of code in my `functions.php` which caused wrong javascript to be loaded.

When you are having the same problem, be sure to search for something like `wp_enqueue_media();` or something of the following script, comment out and try to upload a thumbnail.

```
if( function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) ){
    wp_enqueue_media();
} else {
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
}
```

Thanks for all answers, though.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add support for thumbnails in your theme. So, put this in your theme files:

`function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );`

This enables the thumbnail/feature image support for all post types in your current theme including normal posts and pages.

Comment: I already have this in my code.

Comment: If Dominik had this not enabled it would not even be shown in the editor.

Comment: Try activating/deactivating your plugins to see if that is the case if not try another theme and then set the thumbnail. This will narrow down you issue.

Comment: @Charles Agreed

Comment: @TalwinderSingh I just posted an answer, where I solved it by myself. Thanks, though!